# Building a server side autocomplete in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, arraylist, server-side

I wanted to know if it's possible to build an auto complete feature on server side (using ASP.NET & C#). Let say I have a class City...

```
public class City
{
    public string m_CityName;
    public string m_CityId;
    public City() { }
    public City(string cityName, string cityId) 
    { m_CityName = cityName; m_CityId = cityId; }
}
```

With this, I build an ArrayList of City on the server side. What I want is to build an auto-complete that will display the name of the city, but will return the id of the city.

Can I do this on the server side or I must do it on client side?
If I need to do it on client-side, what is the best, fastest and **safest** way to do it.

The data of cities, name and id, are coming from an XML file.

Thank you.

Comment: Use AJAX : **http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx**, You can do it on client side as well : **http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/**

Comment: I'm trying to use Ajax, but I've used this before, so I'm learning. I wanted to know if there was another way of doing it.

Comment: Without being too specific (yes, this is a drive-by comment), what you'd want to do is...  1) Expose the server-side functionality as a service (web method, perhaps? some sort of handler which returns JSON). This service would accept a string and return matches on that string.  Those matches can be whole objects, just represented in JSON.  2) Write client-side JavaScript to respond to the UI events (keypress) and use AJAX to contact that service.

Comment: @Triwis: Yes the second url I put in the comment describes a way that you can do with JSON

Comment: @Triwis: "another way of doing it" - Not really.  There's a hard separation between client-side and server-side.  The client-side is handling the UI events and has to make discrete requests to the server and get responses.  In the absence of full page re-loads (which wouldn't make for a very good auto-complete), it would need to use AJAX.  One tip is to do the lookup on a slight delay (100ms - 200ms, maybe) so that you're not bombarding the server with requests while someone quickly types.

Comment: I think building a Webserive that returns JSON and using AJAX to call this webservice would be the best way of doing my auto-complete feature. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use AJAX as stated previously. It is generally a better idea (in my experience) to let the server manage data logic.

But you can load XML using jQuery if it's a static file.  One example here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file/

With both the AJAX and jQuery XML methods it's careful to not bombard the server (or client) with requests, in the past I have limited the search to every third key press and the length of the search being over three characters as well. But as mentioned by David delaying the requests could also be an option.